# ¿Como mostrar la fecha en itextsharp trabajando en vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itextsharp

Estoy trabajando en una boleta y necesito que se muestre la hora en la que se realizó. Estoy utilizando la librería Itextsharp para que se guarde como PDF. No sé como llevar la fecha al PDF, ya que de esta forma me aparece "false" en el PDF en vez de la fecha

```
            Dim cb As PdfContentByte = writer.DirectContent
        Dim bf As BaseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.COURIER_BOLD, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED)


        cb.BeginText()
        cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 11)
        cb.SetTextMatrix(10, 210)
        cb.ShowText("Rut: ")

        cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 11)
        cb.SetTextMatrix(10, 200)
        cb.ShowText("Cliente:")

        cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 11)
        cb.SetTextMatrix(10, 190)
        cb.ShowText("Dirección:")

        cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 11)
        cb.SetTextMatrix(10, 180)
        cb.ShowText("Teléfono:")

        cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 11)
        cb.SetTextMatrix(10, 170)
        cb.ShowText("Localidad:")

        cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 11)
        cb.SetTextMatrix(10, 160)
        cb.ShowText("Fecha:" & DateTimePicker1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))

        cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 11)
        cb.SetTextMatrix(10, 110)
        cb.ShowText("Descripción:")
        cb.EndText()
```

Comment: ¿Y qué has hecho hasta ahora? Edita la pregunta con tu código para ver por dónde tirar.

Comment: Ya lo he editado gracias por responder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No entiendo por qué usas el datetimepicker y le asignas la fecha actual. Intenta con uno de los dos.

Este toma el valor seleccionado

```
cb.ShowText("Fecha:" & DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
```

O si quieres la fecha actual

```
cb.ShowText("Fecha:" & DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias eso funciono :D